# Does Illusion Mastery (Item Mastery) consume charges on rods, or scrolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats

The feat [Illusion Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-mastery-feats/illusion-mastery-item-mastery/) allows you to cast minor image instead of the illusion spell stored in a rod or scroll once per day. When you do so, does it consume a charge from the rod, or does it destroy the scroll? Or can you continue to use it as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Item mastery feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-mastery-feats/) typically need nonexpendable magic items that don't require that they be recharged

[Item Mastery Feats](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-mastery-feats/), in part, says

> Magic item mastery is stressful for the item as well as the user and can’t be performed on items that can be used only a limited number of times or that must be recharged (such as elixirs, potions, scrolls, staffs, and wands)—it requires items with constant effects or daily uses. Magic item mastery doesn’t affect an item’s normal properties or deplete any of its daily uses.

Thus the typical scroll can't be used in conjunction with item mastery feats. Magic rods, on the other hand, must be assessed on a case-by-case basis; for example, a [*rod of cancellation*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-cancellation/) can't be used to fuel item mastery feats, but a [*rod of lordly might*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-lordly-might/) can (although not the feat [Illusion Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-mastery-feats/illusion-mastery-item-mastery/)!).

Comment: Right, totally missed that page, since I just clicked through straight to Illusion Mastery. Thanks!